# mysql GROUPING and GROUP_CONCAT returns NULL

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat

right now i can't really understand 2 Things.

this is my initial query:

```
SELECT  orders.order_id, 
    orders.artikel_id, 
    orders.count,
    material_list.artikelname,
    material_list.sn_required,
    COUNT(DISTINCT material_history.sn_id) AS sn_cnt,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(material_list.sn_required,material_sn.sn,NULL)) AS sn_list
FROM orders 
INNER JOIN material_list
    ON orders.artikel_id=material_list.artikel_id
    AND materialbestellung.bestell_id='048976'
LEFT JOIN (material_sn, material_history)
    ON orders.artikel_id=material_sn.artikel_id
    AND material_history.sn_id=material_sn.id
    AND orders.order_id=material_history.assignment_id
    AND material_history.assignment='order_id'
    AND material_sn.aktuelle_id_historie=material_history.mat_historie_id
GROUP BY orders.artikel_id
ORDER BY artikelname ASC
```

this query should list orders AND already assigned material to the specified order.

but in some particular cases it doesn't work and i don't know why

material_sn and material_history HAVA TO HAVE corresponding entries

the result of the query above for example:

```
order_id  artikel_id  count  artikelname  sn_required  sn_cnt  sn_list  
048976    348         1      XXX          1            0       (NULL)      
048976    7           0      YYY          1            0       (NULL)
```

now i change the query to the following:

```
SELECT  orders.order_id, 
    orders.artikel_id, 
    orders.count,
    material_list.artikelname,
    material_list.sn_required,
    COUNT(DISTINCT material_history.sn_id) AS sn_cnt,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(material_list.sn_required,material_sn.sn,NULL)) AS sn_list
FROM orders 
INNER JOIN material_list
    ON orders.artikel_id=material_list.artikel_id
    AND materialbestellung.bestell_id='048976'
LEFT JOIN material_history
    ON orders.order_id=material_history.assignment_id
    AND material_history.assignment='order_id'
LEFT JOIN material_sn
    ON orders.artikel_id=material_sn.artikel_id 
    AND material_sn.aktuelle_id_historie=material_history.mat_historie_id
    AND material_history.sn_id=material_sn.id
GROUP BY orders.artikel_id
ORDER BY artikelname ASC
```

now i get the following result:

```
order_id    artikel_id  count  artikelname sn_required sn_cnt  sn_list  
048976      348         1      XXX         1           1       (NULL)
048976      7           0      YYY         1           1       (NULL)
```

at this point 
 sn_cnt=1 is corrent for article XXX but not for YYY, also sn_list shouldn't be NULL

IF i leave out "GROUP BY orders.artikel_id" then i get the following:

```
order_id    artikel_id  count  artikelname srequired  sn_cnt  sn_list  
048976      348         1      XXX         1          1       123442450269
```

how can that be?

i'm using mysql 5.7

thanks!

Comment: `LEFT JOIN material_sn
    AND orders.artikel_id=material_sn.artikel_id ` Do you intend to write `ON orders.artikel_id ...` here instead of AND?

Comment: yes that should be ON, i've corrected my mistake, do you know why its happening?

Comment: Thinking on lines of `LEFT JOIN (t2, t3, t4)` does `LEFT JOIN (t2 CROSS JOIN t3 CROSS JOIN t4)`. But too many tables involved to wrap around my head.  Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: yeah i already read this, what i understood until now is, that i can't use additional conditions in cross-join

Comment: but to get rid of the cross join i separated both tables in 2 left joins, so cross join wouldn't be a Problem, althoughit would be interesting why step 1 make such a difference even if cross-join SHOULD work, step 2 is the essential one

Comment: hm nobody an idea?